# How can I delete Minecraft when Java thinks there's still a file open?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I want to delete Minecraft, but its not working. It told me that Minecraft was open but it isn't. I tried deleting the file and it told me that Java TM is not allowing it.

How can I delete it?

[image: "Java(TM) is not allowing it.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a video game related problem. The problem you are having is involving a video game, but would happen with any java application; or in fact, any other application. Try Super User for questions directed to general computer use.

Comment: reboot and then try deleting it

Answer (score 5):

You have to close Minecraft (the Java<sup>TM</sup> Virtural Machine) before you can delete Minecraft.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the **Run...** dialog.
2. Type in `taskkill /f /im javaw.exe` into the dialog.
3. Now you can delete Minecraft.

Comment: Similar method, Ctrl + Shift + Escape, close all the java processes.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the remaining files are on a Windows computers.

C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft

You can access it easily by %appdata%\.minecraft

Deleting the "bin" and "resources" folder would delete ALL textures, models, and sounds.
You will automatically re-download the files to their default properties the next time you run the game.

If you're on Mac, I do not have a clue where the directory is.
If you're on Windows, "appdata" is a hidden folder in your user files.

Comment: He knows where to delete the files, not why he can't delete them.